# How to fix Navigation with focus and hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the thing, I want to move the div with class "effect" () when every tab is on hover, in other words: I just want an sliding underline menu

On my first attempt I try to move it with ":hover" css pseudo class but it works just with one direction, this time (check the snippet) I tried with jquery, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong it doesn't work... I want to keep the :focus pseudo class but also the underline sliding movement when is hover, I'm looking the better crossbrowsing and SEO solution for this, 'cause I heard that navigations with javascript have troubles with SEO.

thanks for your knowledge!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.two').focus(function(){
      $('.three').hover(function(){
        $('.ph-line-nav .effect').addClass('moveright');
        }, function(){
        $('.ph-line-nav .effect').removeClass('moveright');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}
.width {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size: 110%;
    display: table;
    background: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
nav a {
    text-align:center;
    background: #FFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 2% 0;
    width: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .4s;
    color: #333;
  /*border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;*/
}
/* ========================
    Lava-lamp-line:
   ======================== */
 .effect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
nav a:nth-child(1):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 0%;
    /* the middle of the first <a> */
}
nav a:nth-child(2):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 25%;
    /* the middle of the second <a> */
}
nav a:nth-child(3):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 50%;
    /* the middle of the third <a> */
}

nav a:nth-child(4):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 75%;
    /* the middle of the forth <a> */
}

.moveright {
      left: 50%;
} 

.ph-line-nav .effect {
    width: /*55px*/ 25%;
    height: .25rem;
    bottom: 5px;
    background: /*#00ABE8*/tomato;
    margin-left:/*-45px*/auto;
    margin-right:/*-45px*/auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width">
<nav class="ph-line-nav">
    <a href="#" class="one">News</a>
    <a href="#" class="two">Activities</a>
    <a href="#" class="three">Search</a>
    <a href="#" class="four">Time</a>
    <div class="effect"></div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: please check again, I modify it

Comment: the snippet is above.. check it

Comment: The actual snippet works just as a "focus" effect, but not as a hover effect, I want to move that underline when I am on hover too not just when I click on every tab.

Comment: prove it yourself, is gonna work just the hover effect,I want it to work the focus effect too, I'm explaining myself? I want it to work both effects, hover and focus

Answer (score 0):

Closer to what you are looking to get?

```js
$(document).hover(function(){
  $('.ph-line-nav .effect').addClass('moveright');
  }, function(){
  $('.ph-line-nav .effect').removeClass('moveright');
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}
.width {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size: 110%;
    display: table;
    background: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
nav a {
    text-align:center;
    background: #FFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 2% 0;
    width: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .4s;
    color: #333;
  /*border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;*/
}
/* ========================
    Lava-lamp-line:
   ======================== */
 .effect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
nav a:nth-child(1):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 0%;
    /* the middle of the first <a> */
}
nav a:nth-child(2):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 25%;
    /* the middle of the second <a> */
}
nav a:nth-child(3):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 50%;
    /* the middle of the third <a> */
}

nav a:nth-child(4):focus ~ .effect {
    left: 75%;
    /* the middle of the forth <a> */
}

.moveright {
      left: 50%;
} 

.ph-line-nav .effect {
    width: /*55px*/ 25%;
    height: .25rem;
    bottom: 5px;
    background: /*#00ABE8*/tomato;
    margin-left:/*-45px*/auto;
    margin-right:/*-45px*/auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width">
<nav class="ph-line-nav">
    <a href="#" class="one">News</a>
    <a href="#" class="two">Activities</a>
    <a href="#" class="three">Search</a>
    <a href="#" class="four">Time</a>
    <div class="effect"></div>
</nav>
</div>
```